# For which parameter this kind of series converges

Tags: convergence-divergence

The sum is the following:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a}{k^b}$

For which parameters this serie converges(***a*** and ***b***)?

Comment: what have you tried? what result do you know that can possibly solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may apply the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) to $\displaystyle f(x):=\frac{a}{x^b}$,
$$
\int_1^N f(x)\,dx\le\sum_{k=1}^N f(k)\le f(1)+\int_1^N f(x)\,dx,\qquad N>1,
$$ and see it converges *iff* $\,b>1$.